# Oracle SQL Developer how to get Min unix timestamp for max order per line

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

im running Oracle Database 18c Enterprise Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0
i have a table like the following:

| Unix_Timestamp | Line | Order_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1660496421 | 1 | 299 |
| 1670496421 | 1 | 299 |
| 1660456421 | 1 | 298 |
| 1660473051 | 1 | 298 |
| 1660573526 | 2 | 300 |
| 1660473044 | 2 | 300 |

Unix_Timestamp is a unique column
i want to get the min Unix_Timestamp value for the max Order_Number value per Line.
so get the most recent order per line, and get the min Unix_Timestamp for that order_number
Order_Number value goes up in ascending value and each number can only belong to one Line.

i do not need the order_number value in my dataset but i need it considered in my script

so far i can get the min Unix_Timestamp value per line but im struggling to factor in the max order_number:

```
select Line,
Min(Unix_Timestamp) as Unix_Timestamp
from..
join..
where..
group by Line
```

any help would be appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [keep last](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC):

> When you need a value from the first or last row of a sorted group, but the needed value is not the sort key, the FIRST and LAST functions eliminate the need for self-joins or views and enable better performance.

In your case you can do:

```
select line,
  min(unix_timestamp) keep (dense_rank last order by order_number) as unix_timestamp
from your_table
group by line

LINE UNIX_TIMESTAMP
---- --------------
   1 1660496421
   2 1660473044
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=22ce3be56ccfb4a6f25ed82c68194ddb)

(The difference between the outputs is hard to spot - 1660496421 looks very similar to 1660456421...)